# Is it more beneficial to just kill everyone?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, there is a regular quest called the "Game Show", where you travel through a dwelling populated with Bandits asking you trivia about Fallout 3 and 4.

If you get a question right, you get a prize (caps). If you get it wrong, they attack you (with terrible puns as well as weapons), and when you kill them all, you get to loot their bodies (for caps and other random gear). The final prize is a Lunchbox, which you get regardless. (You can loot it from a cupboard once you have finished the quiz).

So, in terms of reward, is it better to try and get all the answers right, or just kill everybody?

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/7CcDqq ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In the long run, you will make up those caps through other means (maybe even selling the loot you get), but by killing them you also get XP, which the caps won't buy you.  Also, given that it takes caps + stuff to make weapons, just getting the weapons outright would be a net bonus.

However! For someone who has a maxed out party with legendary weaps and outfits, caps definitely aren't going to be worth it either, but they might be the *faster* option compared to combat.